# Как исправить показ слайдов в галерее?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Помогите со слайдером. Есть 2 блоки: 1й - там отображается текущее изображение, 2-й - это список изображений. Когда мы находимся на первом изображении во 2-м блоке, то в 1-м блоке также оно отображается, но когда выбираем второе изображение во 2-м блоке, то в 1-м отображается пустота, хотя должно все отображаться. Подскажите, в чем проблема? Вот исполняемый код - `codepen.io/anon/pen/xGMwQo`

`kenwheeler.github.io/slick` - Slider Syncing называется. Должно работать как тут

Answer (score 1):

С моей стороны всё отображается.

Проверено в FFox 39, Chrome 41, IE 11.